# Class jwt-auth does not exist error when using middleware in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, jwt

I followed the official JWT-Auth installation https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation.

I now have a middleware in my controller:

`$this->middleware('jwt-auth', ['only' => ['postChange', 'postChoose']]);`

I have also add `Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class` to providers array in `config/app.php`

However when I make a request to the API I get this error message:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 737:
Class jwt-auth does not exist
```

Any help at all will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have the same problem to use the middlewares you will have to register them in `app/Http/Kernel.php` under the `$routeMiddleware` property:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken',
    'jwt.refresh' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken',
];
```

Comment: I have registered it ..are you using jwt.auth or jwt-auth as the middleware

Comment: @digitlimit I am using jwt.auth as middleware.

Comment: Thanks. Seems the official documentation is not very informative.

Comment: Do you run PHPUnit tests? I am trying to make a request by using token in a test getting errors

Comment: Remember to place those single quotes ('). They are very important.

Answer (score 3):

I have been facing a similar issue.
You have to add exactly

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    .......
    'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
];
```

Remember the "\" at the begining.

Laravel 5.2

Comment: Valid in laravel 8 as well

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and turned out that "\" is required on the begin of the path (per analogy to the other middleware entries) :

```
'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class
```

and this resolved my problem (Laravel 5.1.4)